# Get wireless charging info

Tags: android

I write an app which is logging battery status, but there is a problem with `BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS`.
If I load my Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4 or even S4 with 4.2.2 on a wireless charging station, the app display 1 (`BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC`) instead of 4 (`BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS`).
The Phone display a popup, which notice wireless charging. So is it an api bug?

Can anybody confirm this? Is there an other workaround to get the charging mode?

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);
        Toast.makeText(context, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be an API bug from Samsung. Have you tried other phones like nexus?

Comment: no i havn't so much telephones :). what i'm confused about, my api doesn't understand `BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS`. Isn't it in `4.2.2`?

Answer (score -1):

If I get it right you want to know if device is charging or is not. I think that the problem solution should be written like this:

```
public class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED))
    {
        //do something when device is charging
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED))
    {
        //do something when device is not charging
    }
}

}
```

In the xml then the receiver will look like this.

```
    <receiver android:name=".DataReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Hope it helped you. :-)

Comment: It Looks like JaMaBing is getting the power connect notifications just fine, the heart of the question was regarding why they get a status of 1 (BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC) instead of 4 (BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS).

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i have this already. Of course i would know if its loading, its wireless charging, when i see it. But the App should log it and later i dont know this. Like headline said: Get wireless charging info :)